# Remote connection MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL server that it is supposed to connect to others 2 servers with mysqli_connect. The remote connection should only listen to an X IP address.

I tried by adding this SQL command to the database and flush the privileges

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'LISTED_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

but it still not working with

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("host1", "user", "the_password");
if (!$conn) {
    exit("Oops, we can't connect.");
}
```

Also, I changed in /etc/mysql/my.cnf I added a # before bind-address

The three servers is Ubuntu 14.04 and using PHP 7.0

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The following error is ```Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'listed_server' (using password: YES)```

Comment: for testing try `'user'@'%'` thats any IP

Comment: Same error, still denied.

Comment: You don't need to use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after `GRANT`. That's only needed when you modify the privileges table directly with SQL.

Comment: i would be triple checking username and password at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pw="";
$db="database";
$connection=new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
if (!$connection) {
    exit("Oops, we can't connect.");
}
```

Comment: well then its not a remote connection as you said in the original question @vankk